# Mirror foreignobject in svg

Tags: svg

I'm working on some Pen (I wan to create Depth of Field effect), I have html code inside foreign object and I want to apply filter + mask to to that element, for this I need to clone the element and mask it (or is there other way to apply mask to filter?)

I've tried with svg:use

```
<foreignobject id="code">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <figure class="highlight">
          <!-- HTML -->
        </figure>
    </body>
</foreignobject>
<use x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
     filter="url(#blur)" mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="#code"/>
```

but it don't work with foreign objects:

Here is my pen: https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/VwwzVXO

Is there any other way I can use foreign objec to mirror it so I can apply filter+mask?

Comment: you can't point a use at a foreignObject. Filters and masks are irrelevant.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes I know, that's why I've asked about different way to have filter+mask or different way to mirror element.

Comment: put the foreignObject in a <g> and apply the filter/mask to the <g>

Comment: @RobertLongson It require two elements, because mask is applied to content not to filter so to see element without filter I need background that look the same as the element I'm masking.

Comment: Use two nested <g> elements if you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson this will not work because DOM have one root, you need two elements if you hid inner outer can show it what inside hide. If this is doable please create code that works, I don't think it's possible with nesting.

Comment: <g filter="filterurl"><g mask="mask url"><foreignObject></foreignObject></g></g> (or swap the filter and mask if you need to).

Comment: @RobertLongson mask with hide the content of the foreignObject, I want to mask the filter not the content.

Comment: swap the filter and mask <g> elements then.

Comment: @RobertLongson this will be exactly the same, just try.

Comment: one's masking the filter the other's filtering the mask. They might be the same if those operations are interchangeable.

Comment: @RobertLongson filter and mask don't work on parent `g` at all, same as use don't work.

Comment: It works for me in Firefox if you fix all the markup and CSS typos i.e. replace foreignobject by the correct form which is foreignObject

Comment: @RobertLongson can you create a PoC if it work? I can't make it work, if I use filter or mask on g the filter is not applied in Chrome, it only work on `foreginObject`. I've updated the name nothing changed.

Comment: I've only tried on Firefox and I explained the steps I took in my previous comment.

Comment: @RobertLongson it also don't work in Firefox when I've tested. If you think you have an answer then create one but it need work. In FF blur on g works but mask don't, and it's not possible that this will work in any case because mask is not applied to filter but to content I want to mask the filter not the content with filter.